# 1st request dispatcher takes me to account.html correctly but next time in if clause it doesnt taken to deposit.html

Tags: java, servlets

```
public class AccountProcessingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/account.html").forward(request, response);
        String account_type=request.getParameter("accounttype");
        String process=request.getParameter("process");
        System.out.println(account_type);
        System.out.println(process);


        if(account_type == "savingsaccount" || process == "deposit" ){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/deposit.html").forward(request,response);

        }

    }

}
```

IN console: savingsaccount
            deposit
is getting printed but it does not takes to that html page

Comment: forwarding to another component basically means: I've done my work for this request, do your part, I'm done. You shouldn't do anything anymore after you have forwarded the request. You should also learn how to compare strings in Java.

Comment: As suggested by @JBNizet, use .equals method for string comparison and for the request forwarding, create a new object of HttpServletRequest and use getRequestDispatcher and forward on top of it